# Find a Base for the following verctor space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$, spanned by the vectors **a, b** and **c**, with

$$\textbf{a} = (2,1,3,1,-1),\hspace{1mm}b=(4,-3,5,1,1),\hspace{1mm}c=(-1,2,-2,7,3)$$

*(a)* Use any test you like to determine if the given vectors are linearly independent.

*(b)* From among the vectors **a, b** and **c**, select an ordered basis $\mathfrak{B}$ for $V$. (You need to prove that vectors you propose actuually form a basis for $V$).

I row reduced the matrix whoes columns are **a,b,c** and I only have the trivial solution for the system $$c_1\textbf{a}+c_2\textbf{b}+c_3\textbf{c}=0$$

which means **a,b,c** are linearly independent. I'm confused about part *(b)* because from what I have a bases for $V$ would be $\mathfrak{B}=\lbrace\textbf{a},\textbf{b},\textbf{c}\rbrace$.

am I missing something because part (b) of the question is worth 10 points and it seems I don't have to do anything to solve it.

Comment: Don't you need to **row** reduce the matrix whose **rows** are $\bf a$, $\bf b$ and $\bf c$? If you put them as columns then you're working with the vectors $(2,4,-1)$, $(1,-3,2)$, $(3,5,-2)$, $(1,1,7)$ and $(-1,1,3)$.

Comment: The vectors *are* linearly independent. Are you sure you have copied them right?

Comment: @egreg yes I'm sure

Answer (score 1):

From row reducing the matrix with ROWS $a$,$b$ and $c$ you get that the rank of the matrix is $3$ which means that $a$,$b$ and $c$ are linearly independent. For the second question,as you mentioned,all you have to say is that $B = {(a,b,c)} $ because you know that $a$,$b$ and $c$ are independent and span the vector $V$.